# Python Regex sub on single character

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to perform a sub on only one character of a matching pattern?

For example, if I have the string

```
"This is a word. This is another word. H.E. Stein"
```

and I want to perform a sub on just the '.'s at the end of a sentence so it becomes

```
"This is a word This is another word H.E. Stein"
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Why RegEx and did you Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expression:

```
>>> "qwerty.".replace('.', '', 1) # 1 -> replace count (only once)
'qwerty'
```

To delete the last character, use slice:

```
>>> "qwerty."[:-1]
'qwerty'
```

**UPDATE** according to the question edit.

```
>>> text = "This is a word. This is another word. H.E. Stein"
>>> re.sub(r'(\w{2})\.', r'\1', text)
'This is a word This is another word H.E. Stein'
```

`(\w{2})\.`: to match a period just after two word characters. capture the word characters as group 1. later referenced as `\1`.

Comment: The reason I need regular expressions is because I might have a sentence that is: "This is a word. This is another word. H.E. Stein." And I want to be able to get rid of all the periods at the end of sentences but not acronyms.

Comment: @Mozbi, So you want `"This is a word This is another word H.E. Stein"
` as a reuslt. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks a lot falsetru! you're awesome. Thanks for the exaplanations